# How handle decimal and thousands separators for numbers in Parsley.js?

Tags: parsley.js

I can see that Parsley.js handle English separators for numbers.

When I use Parsley with Spanish numbers it doesn't work (example : 5,50 is not a valid number for Parsley and in my country comma is our decimal separator).

Is there some config to change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create the necessary regex that matches your needs. A (probably rudimentary) regex would be `^\d+(,\d+)?$`, that matches any digits or digits with commas.

You don't even need to create a [custom validator](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft), since Parsley allows you to use `data-parsley-pattern` which receives a regex.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.0.7/parsley.min.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <input type="text" name="commaNumbers" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d+)?$" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but this solution helps me too. I'd just modified/changed the pattern from Luis Cruz code so that the field will handle decimal places. (ex. 1,000,000,000.30)

Hope this helps too.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.0.7/parsley.min.js"></script>
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <input type="text" name="commaNumbers" data-parsley-pattern="^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$" required/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```